# Meaning of の in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particles, nominalization

The sentence is

> それがいかなる彼女の琴線に触れたのかはわからない

I believe that かは is embedding the question (as seen [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61495/what-does-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%af-mean)) but I'm a little confused at what role の is playing here. Is it simply nominalizing the previous sentence? and if so why is it playing this role?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verb+のを meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57187/verb%e3%81%ae%e3%82%92-meaning)

Comment: Unfortunately not really. I suppose the bigger issues I'm having here is if の is being used in the manner described in that question in this sentence why is it doing so in this particular sentence (i.e. does the construction かは require a noun in the same way as を）?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/83440/choukai-discussing-a-business-trip/83446#83446).

Comment: @EddieKal This one is explanatory-no, so it's different from the の in your link.

Comment: Does this answer your question?: [Is the の\[か\] in my sentence a 準体言助詞 の\[か\]?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74004/5010) `のか` is a literary-style question ender, but it's common in embedded questions where です is not used.

Comment: Ah I see so just to clarify one minor point は in this case is simply serving as a topic marker?

Comment: @Xanadulo Yes, the topic marker. "I don't understand which part/type of her heartstring it plucked."